# Coverting String to String Array for RestTemplate Response in Spring

Tags: java, arrays, spring, string

I am using rest template in spring to make an external call and i am getting the below response:

```
RestTemplate tm = new RestTemplate();
String resp = 
tm.exchange(url,HttpMethod.GET,requestEntity,String.class).getBody();
```

resp return below response:
["JAVA",
"C++",
"Python",
"Basic"
]

i want to convert this to Java String array.

Currently i am doing:

```
resp = resp.substring(1,len-1);//to remove []
String[] arry = resp.split(",");
for(String a: arr){
System.out.println(a);//gives as "JAVA","C++"..etc
}
```

how can i directly get string array or even a List???
Is there a better approach.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
tm.exchange(url,HttpMethod.GET,requestEntity,String[].class).getBody();
```

Comment: Thank you that really helps

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
tm.exchange(url, HttpMethod.GET, requestEntity, 
new ParameterizedTypeReference<List<String>>() {}).getBody();
```